# How to display the images I save in the public folder on my nodejs backend server?

Tags: node.js, axios, vue-cli

At last I was able to upload the images from vue cli in the frontend and pass them with axios to my backend server, but once there I do not know what to do to show them
... translated whith Google

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: If you upload the file on "upload" folder of the server, the url of the file stored on server will be 'http://server.ip/upload/filename.ext" so your upload route must send back to the client the url in this format. Try to upload a file and test the url with the browser and check if the file will be rendered correctly.

Comment: I'm running the server on Node.js. It is not apache to access the files themselves, most likely it would need a library but no idea what to use since I still can not find the solution

Comment: I finded the answer here http://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html